# Is this a fine std::auto_ptr<> use case?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr, exception-safe

Please suppose I have a function that accepts a pointer as a parameter. This function can throw an exception, as it uses `std::vector<>::push_back()` to manage the lifecycle of this pointer. If I declare it like this:

```
void manage(T *ptr);
```

and call it like this:

```
manage(new T());
```

if it throws an exception pushing the pointer into the `std::vector<>`, I effectively have got a memory leak, haven't I?

Would declaring the function like this:

```
void manage(std::auto_ptr<T> ptr);
```

solve my problem?

I would expect it to first allocate the `std::auto_ptr` on the stack (something that I guess couldn't ever throw an exception) and let it acquire ownership over the pointer. Safe.

Then, inside the function, I would push the raw pointer into the `std::vector<>`, which is also safe: if this fails, the pointer will not be added, but the smart pointer will still be owning the pointer so it will be destroyed. If the pushing succeeds, I would remove the smart pointer's ownership over that pointer and return: this can't throw an exception, so it will always be fine.

Are my theories correct?

-- Edit --

No, I think I can't do that. Doing that would require taking a non-const reference to rvalue (to take away ownership from the smart pointer). I would have to write

```
std::auto_ptr<T> ptr(new T());
manage(ptr);
```

for that to work, something that's quite inconvient in my case. I'm writing this so that I can implement RAII without polluting much the code. Doing that thing would not help, then. That would be catch 22.

-- Edit 2 --

Pulling what Jason Orendorff said down there here for quick reference by readers, the ultimate solution seems to be the following:

```
void manage(T *ptr)
{
    std::auto_ptr<T> autoPtr(ptr);
    vector.push_back(ptr);
    autoPtr.release();
}
```

This solves the problem of the useless non-const reference to rvalue.

When I finish this class I'm coding I'll post it back here in case anyone finds it useful.

-- Edit 3 --

Ok, there has been a lot of discussion here, and there are key points that I should have clarified before. In general, when I post at stackoverflow, I try to explain the reason behind my questions and, in general, that is completely useless. So this time I thought I should go straight to the point. Turns out it didn't work quite well XD

Unfortunately my brain is deadlocking now, so I think I won't even be able to explain correctly what I first thought to accomplish my goals. I am trying to find a good solution for atomic operations and exception-safe code writing that fits lots of cases, but really, I can't handle it XD I think this is the kind of thing I will only master with time.

I am a really new C++ programmer and my focus is game development. When an exception is thrown in a game engine, it is the end of execution. The system will free all the memory for my process, so it doesn't really matter if one or two pointers leak here and there. Now that I am developing a server application, I'm finding it hard to deal with exceptions, because an exception can't crash the server; it must "crash the request".

That is, "Well, client, unfortunately the developers didn't foresee this condition, so you'll have to try it later (up to here, it is basically the same thing as with a game engine, nothing is being repared, only it is isolated to the context of just a request, and not the whole process). But don't panic, as *everything was left in a valid state* (here is one of the differences, however. The process isn't terminated, so the operating system can't free the resources for you; furthermore, you have to pay attention to undo the operations so far, so that you don't lock completely an user's account, for example, or even a full service provided by the server).".

I will just code more and more and note down my problems so that I can write a better question next time. I wasn't prepared to ask this now, I'm really sorry.

Thanks a lot for your replies, I really like stackoverflow. It is absolutely amazing how fast my questions are answered and how enlightening your answers are. Thanks.

Comment: Doing it this way would give `manage` a rather odd interface - it is expected to delete its argument in all circumstances (either by keeping it or deleting it itself).  Why does it not handle the allocation on its own rather than exposing it via `auto_ptr`?  I see `auto_ptr` as being primarily for internal implementation, not interface.

Comment: Indeed, the interface got unnecessarily odd. I fixed that per suggested by Jason Orendorff.

Comment: One difficulty still remains - is it really supposed to take ownership if it fails? It seems to me that RAII and exception-safety would suggest that, if `manage` fails, then it has not taken ownership of the pointer and thus the caller still owns it (and therefore must free it). That can get complicated though.

Comment: To me that last solution (by Jason) is the complete anti-pattern of how it should be. It goes against all the RAII and exception safety work done in the last 10 years. If you own a pointer you should never expose it as a RAW pointer in the code (it should always be wrapped in a smart pointer). Your original idea of exposing the auto_ptr in the interface is absolutely correct and clearly indicates the transfer of ownership to manager(). An example from boost: look at boost::ptr_vector it has this exact interface.

Comment: And since Martin York talked about it: Really read about `boost::ptr_vector` rather than using a raw `std::vector` to store pointers > you'll avoid unnecessary cleanup mistakes.

Comment: I'm really curios as to what `manage()` actually does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think enough discussion has been generated to warrant yet another answer.

Firstly, to answer the actual question, yes, it is absolutely appropriate (and even necessary!) to pass an argument by smart pointer when ownership transfer occurs. Passing by a smart pointer is a common idiom to accomplish that.

```
void manage(std::auto_ptr<T> t) {
    ...
}
...

// The reader of this code clearly sees ownership transfer.
std::auto_ptr<T> t(new T);
manage(t);
```

Now, there is a very good reason why all smart pointers have explicit constructors. Consider the following function (mentally replace `std::auto_ptr` with `boost::shared_ptr` if it tickles your fancy):

```
void func(std::auto_ptr<Widget> w, const Gizmo& g) {
    ...
}
```

If `std::auto_ptr` had an implicit constructor, suddenly this code would compile:

```
func(new Widget(), gizmo);
```

What's wrong with it? Taking almost directly from "Effective C++", Item 17:

```
func(new Widget(), a_function_that_throws());
```

Because in C++ order of argument evaluation is undefined, you can very well have arguments evaluated in the following order: `new Widget()`, `a_function_that_throws()`, `std::auto_ptr` constructor. If a function throws, you have a leak.

Therefore all resources that will be released *need* to be wrapped upon construction in RAII classes *before* being passed into a function. This means all smart pointer have to be constructed before passing them as an argument to a function. Making smart pointers be copy-constructible with a const reference or implicitly-constructible would encourage unsafe code. Explicit construction enforces safer code.

Now, why shouldn't you do something like this?

```
void manage(T *ptr)
{
    std::auto_ptr<T> autoPtr(ptr);
    vector.push_back(ptr);
    autoPtr.release();
}
```

As already mentioned, the interface idioms tell me that I can pass a pointer that I own and I get to delete it. So, nothing stops me from doing this:

```
T item;
manage(&t);

// or
manage(&t_class_member);
```

Which is disastrous, of course. But you'd say "of course I know what the interface means, I'd never use it that way". However you may want to add an extra argument to a function later. Or someone (not you, or you 3 years later) comes along this code, they may not see it the same way as you do.

1. This hypothetical "someone else" may only see a header without a comment and (rightly) presume the lack of ownership transfer.
2. They may see how this function is used in some other code and replicate the usage without looking at the header.
3. They may use code auto-completion to invoke a function and not read the comment or the function and presume the lack of ownership transfer.
4. They may write a function that wraps you `manage` function and yet someone else will use the wrapper function and will miss the documentation of the original function.
5. They may try to "extend" you code so that all the old code compiles (and automatically becomes unsafe):

   ```
   void manage(T *t, const std::string tag = some_function_that_throws());
   ```

As you can see, explicit construction of a smart pointer makes it much harder to write unsafe code in the above cases.

Therefore, I would not recommend going against decades of C++ expertise to make perceivably "nicer" and "fun" API.

My 2c.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way, but you still have to cleanup in the event of an exception not being thrown, which seems a little onerous.

If you use something like [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) (I believe something like this is in TR1 libraries as well - as an example see [MS's implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx)) you could forget about having to cleanup in the event of things going as planned.

To make this work you would need to make your vector accept `boost::shared_ptr < T >` instance, then you would just let your original instance be cleaned up and it would leave instance in the vector alive in the case that all goes well.  In  the case things go wrong all `boost::shared_ptr` instances would be destroyed and you would still end up with no leak.

With smart pointers it's about picking one that suits the task, and in this case shared ownership (or simple ownership transfer) seems to be a goal so there are better candidates than std::auto_ptr on most platforms.

Comment: It really is my intention to control whether to "cleanup" the objects or not in the event of an exception not being thrown. The class I'm trying to implement is called ScopeRollback. It will execute the boost::functions I add to it in case it is destroyed before being clear()'ed. The problem with using `boost::shared_ptr` is its "viral" nature. I can't take away ownership from a shared_ptr, but I really need that. In any case, I think my code really is wrong. See my edit for details, and thanks for answering.

Comment: @n2liquid: Ah, OK, then this is probably a more specialised case where the cleanup requirement for the caller is maybe justified.  I'd still urge you to peruse the library of boost smart_ptr's if you are already using boost since there are many different ones available.  Maybe another will suit your needs better?

Answer (score 4):

In general, using `std::auto_ptr` as a type of function argument unambiguously tells the caller that function will take ownership of the object, and will be responsible for deleting it. If your function fits that description, then by all means use `auto_ptr` there regardless of any other reason.

Comment: This forces the caller to create an `auto_ptr` object, though, which seems cruel. It's certainly unusual.

Comment: That's precisely the idea. It forces the caller to create an `auto_ptr` (if he doesn't have one already - and if he owns an object on the heap, then he _should_ have one), which makes it clear that 1) the object is owned by one owner at a time, and 2) that ownership is relinquished.

Comment: I can hear the explanation now. "No, you can't just `manage(new T);`. You have to `std::auto_ptr<T> p(new T); manage(p);`." "WTF, why?" "It's for your own good. Now you know that ownership is relinquished." "FML."

Comment: I'm in favor of using type systems to express constraints if (a) the system can actually enforce them (b) they make the code easier to read and understand. To me, `manage(new T)` says clearly enough that the caller expects the function to take ownership. The extra `auto_ptr` doesn't really seem to help, in other words.

Comment: @Jason: The whole point is to express at the interface level that ownership is moved. __This is what auto_ptr does__. If you leave the interface as a pointer it is completely ambiguous what happens to the pointer under the covers, somebody could just take the address of a stack variable and pass it. Your arguments above are counter intuitive (as you should never have a RAW owned pointer anyway (for exception safety owned pointers should always be held in a smart pointer)) and go against the last 10 years of experience and advice by leaders in the field. See Suttter, Alexandrescu and Meyers.

Comment: Look at: manage(new T). Yes this does imply you are giving away the pointer, but does not convey correct usage. The __interface__ is manage(T* ptr). Reading this can you tell that manager is going to take ownership? What happens when I pass the address of stack variable. What happens if I have been using the pointer for a while before I hand it over? Neither of these situations express the transfer of ownership.

Comment: manage(T* ptr): Is also NOT exception safe. What happens if the method throws before the pointer is stored into a container. By using std::auto_ptr you are guaranteeing (to the best of the callers ability) that you are safe from resource leaks. This interface looks exactly like those C string interface we deliberately moved away from because it was never clear who owned the string (and thus who was responsible for clean up).

Comment: I agree that the requirement to use two steps to pass the result of `new T` to a function expection `auto_ptr<T>` is a deficiency, but I consider it a relatively minor one. It's not like you use `new` in that context all the time - if you allocate that pointer earlier at some point, or get it from someone else, it should be an `auto_ptr` by that point, anyway.

Comment: The balance is between expressing as much as you can about the function's contract in the parameter types, on the one hand, and defining an interface that's easy to understand and pleasant to use, on the other.

Comment: Let me be clear -- if C++ actually had linear types, my view on this question would likely be totally different. But it doesn't, and `auto_ptr` is a pretty poor substitute.

Comment: In C++0x, they've added `make_shared<T>()` but not `make_unique<T>()` - the latter would nicely go along with using `unique_ptr` for arguments which transfer ownership while avoiding syntactic baggage. I'm not sure why it was omitted, but fully expect it to pop up in Boost or elsewhere shortly.

Comment: "manage(T* ptr): Is also NOT exception safe." Exception-safety is a property of function definitions, not signatures. "What happens if the method throws before the pointer is stored into a container." What happens if you use `auto_ptr`, and then method throws after the pointer is stored into a container, but before `release()` is called? It would be a bug, obviously. Don't do that.

Comment: Yeah - `unique_ptr` will be much better for this kind of thing.

Comment: "What happens if you use auto_ptr, and then method throws after the pointer is stored into a container, but before release() is called?" - I would assume that you'd use either `std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr>`, or `boost::ptr_vector`, or another container which properly tracks ownership. In which case its `push_back` will accept your `auto_ptr`, and take over in the usual way (by nulling it out). You really shouldn't have explicit `release()` calls except when you interoperate with code written with no `auto_ptr` support (which shouldn't ever happen to be your code ;)

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes, that's fine.</s> *(See edit below.)* (jkp might be seeing something I've missed, but I don't think you "still have to clean up in the event of an exception being thrown" because, as you say, in that case the auto_ptr will delete the object for you.)

But I think it would be better still to hide the auto_ptr shenanigans from the caller:

```
void manage(T *t) {
    std::auto_ptr<T> p(t);  // to delete t in case push_back throws
    vec.push_back(t);
    p.release();
}
```

**EDIT:** I initially wrote "Yes, that's fine," referring to the original `manage(auto_ptr<T>)` plan, but I tried it and found that it doesn't work. The constructor `auto_ptr<T>::auto_ptr(T *)` is `explicit`. The compiler wouldn't let you write `manage(new T)` because it can't implicitly convert that pointer to an `auto_ptr`.  `manage(T *)` is a friendlier interface anyway!

Comment: Ohhhh! Duh! How couldn't I have thought about that? :DD I think that solves the problem I expressed in my edit up there, thanks. In any case, jkp said I would still have to cleanup in the event of an exception NOT being thrown ;) Thank you both.

Comment: @Jason: yeah, I made a typo so maybe you read that.  Anyway, good call on your solution (now I know the context). +1.

Comment: Actually I disagree. By hiding auto_ptr you make it non-obvious to the caller whether the object is being deleted unless you state it in the function comments (which may or may not be read). Passing auto_ptr by value is an excellent way to document the intention of object ownership transfer. The caller will lose the actual pointer value as soon as they pass it into the function and will be left with a NULL-pointer instead of an undefined one.

Comment: @Checkers: Actually the signal you're sending to most C++ programmers is "hi, this interfaces uses some standard library feature you've never had to use before". And it happens to be a rather weird one that's sort of easy to mess up.

Comment: @Checkers: Also, the caller doesn't necessarily lose the pointer value. For example, `T *p = new T; manage(auto_ptr<T>(p)); p->oops();`.

Comment: @Checkers: The class I'm creating is very specific. If the user is using it, he knows under which conditions the class will delete the object for him (whenever the scope is broken before calling clear(), e.g. by an unhandled throw). And, yes, Jason is right. It is not always that the class takes ownership over the pointer. In fact, in the real implementation, the supposed `manage` function returns T*. It will only delete it for the user if something bad happens. I do something like `Socket *s = rollback.deletionWrap(new Socket())` so that the rollback thing doesn't "pollute" much the function.

Comment: And by the way, not only `std::auto_ptr<>()` is explicit, it also takes a non-const reference to another `std::auto_ptr<>`, what means I can't use a temporary. It is really the worst.. :) That smart pointer goes inside. Period.

Comment: @Jason: never had to use before? auto_ptr (and its limitations) should be well-known to any well-rounded C++ programmer. As for your second comment, inline construction of smart pointers in function calls is dangerous (shared_ptr included, see Effective C++, Item 17). A RAII resource must be wrapped in smart pointer in a standalone statement immediately after allocation and used through that smart pointer only.

Comment: @n2liquid, then you really should use shared_ptr, especially if you are passing around pointers between contexts with potentially different lifetimes.